# Windows WriteFile problem when using threads

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, driver, createfile

My company is developing a hardware that needs to communicate with software. To do this, we have made a driver that enables writing to and reading from the hardware. To access the driver, we use the command:

```
HANDLE device = CreateFile(DEVICE_NAME,
                                GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                                0x00000007,
                                &sec,
                                OPEN_EXISTING,
                                0,
                                NULL);
```

Reading and writing is done using the functions:

```
WriteFile(device,&package,package.datasize,&bytesWritten,NULL);
```

and

```
ReadFile(device,returndata,returndatasize,&bytesRead,NULL);
```

And finally, CloseHandle(device), to close the file.

This works just fine in the case where the functions are called from the main thread. If they are called from some other thread, we get error 998 (no_acccess) when trying to Write more than a couple of elements. The threads are created using

```
CreateThread(NULL, 0, thread_func, NULL, 0, &thread_id);
```

I'm running out of ideas here, any suggestions?

edit: 
When running the following sequence:

```
Main_thread:
CreateFile
Write
Close
CreateThread
WaitForThread

Thread_B:
CreateFile
Write
Close
```

Main_Thread succeeds and Thread_B does not. However, when writing small sets of data, this works fine. May this be because Thread_B does not inherit all of Main_Thread's access privileges?

edit2:
a lot of good thinking going on here, much appreciated! After some work on this problem, the following seems to be the case:

The api contains a Queue-thread, handling all packages going to and from the device. This thread handles pointers to package-objects. When a pointer reaches the front of the queue, a "send_and_get" function is called. If the arrays in the package is allocated in the same thread that calls the "send_and_get" function, everything works fine. If the arrays are allocated in some other thread, sending fails. How to fix this, though, I don't know.

Comment: It's not concurrent access is it? - can more than one thread write simultaneously and if so have you protected it?

Comment: Are you doing a CreateFile for each thread, or you just doing it in the main thread and passing the handle to the sub-threads?

Comment: Only one thread is accessing the file at a time. Each thread calls CreateFile, then writes/reads, and finally CloseHandle. After this is done, the next thread can access the file.

Comment: With your flags as they are (0x7) that won't protect it - you've allowed sharing of the file.

Comment: there is a mutex in the API, making sure that only one thread/process/function tries to access it at a time. I've tried other flags, though, with the same result.

Comment: OK. Clutching at straws now - have you tried leaving the handle open from CreateFile in the main thread and passing it to the other threads to use (obviously within your protection)?

Comment: Have you tried hitting it with a hammer?

Comment: Many good ideas here, I especially like the hammer approach :)
Making one handle and reusing it, as you suggested, gave the same result

Comment: I assume you are not using any of the impersonation functions, e.g., ImpersonateLoggedOnUser?

Answer (score 3):

According to winerror, Win32 error 998 is one of the following native status values (which would be returned by the O/S or the driver):

```
   998 ERROR_NOACCESS <--> 0x80000002 STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT
   998 ERROR_NOACCESS <--> 0xc0000005 STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
   998 ERROR_NOACCESS <--> 0xc00002c5 STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT_ERROR
```

Access violation might be a likely candidate based on you saying, "when trying to Write more than a couple of elements." Are you sure the buffer that you're sending is large enough?

The alignment errors are fairly exotic, but might be relevant if the device has some alignment requirements and the developer chose to use these particular errors.

-scott

Comment: I think the buffer is large enough (at least my coworker who wrote the driver claims it is). What puzzles me is that we are able to send large arrays from the main thread, but only small arrays from other threads. Is it possible that some threads don't get access to the buffer in question? if so, any ideas on how to test/fix this?

Comment: Could it possibly be data alignment in the buffer your sending from - i.e. in the main thread it's on the 64bit boundary but in the threads it's not?

Comment: It may be something like that - how does one test for this?

Comment: Try using VirtualAlloc to create each buffer.  This ensures that your buffer is page-aligned.

Answer (score 2):

Still sounds to me like it's concurrent access.
Your separate threads writing to this device will need to properly protect access to the file using a mutex or similar. Either open the handle in the main thread and leave it open or protect the whole Open -> Write -> Close sequence that can occur in each thread (with a mutex).

Comment: It's not. There is a mutex handling synchronization issues. The same problem occurs when running the following sequence: 
Main: [ create - read/write - close - CreateThread ]
Thread: [ create - read/write - close ]
-- Main succeeds, Thread does not

Comment: What if you do nothing in the main thread but start the second thread?  Have you tried running the second thread's code exactly as if it were a separate thread but actually in the main thread?

Comment: I have tried that. It seems to me that what is causing the problem is that the function WriteFile is called from a non-main thread.

Comment: Windows itself doesn't distinguish between the first thread in a process and any others.  It's possible that issue is related to your runtime libraries, so try using the threading support for the language rather than CreateThread.  It could be a stack size issue, so try specifying a large stack in CreateThread.  Finally it could be a bug in your device driver.  Unfortunately in that case there's no easy way to narrow down the possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

As a debugging measure, since it's your own driver, you could get the driver to log the requests it is receiving, e.g., into the event log.  Set up two test runs which are identical except that one runs all the code in the main thread and the other runs all the code in a second thread.  Comparing the results should give you a better insight into what is happening.

It would also be a good idea to get your driver to report any error codes that it is returning to the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

First thing that you should check is if the error (998) reported by your driver or by the kernel-mode I/O manager (which is responsible to initiate the IRP and call your driver) even before the request reaches your driver. You should be able to discover this since this is **your** driver. Just log the calls to the driver's Dispatch routine, what it returns, what it does (does it call other drivers or calls `IoCompleteRequest` with an error code or etc.) and things should become clear.

From the scenario that you describe it seems that most likely the error is caused by your driver. For instance, your driver may allocate some **global** state structure on a response to `CreateFile` (which is driver's `IRP_MJ_CREATE`), and purge it when the file is closed. Such a driver won't function correctly if simultaneously two files are opened, then one is closed whereas the second still receives I/O requests.